# change active environment not working in anaconda jupyter for macintosh

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My root environment uses Python 3.6, but does not have all the same libraries installed as in another environment I set up and named `PY36`.  In testing I am finding that even after I switch environments, libraries I have in root still work and libraries I have only in `PY36` don't work, suggesting that switching environments is not working somehow.  To explain:

in a terminal window:

```
> conda env list
```

Output:

```
base                  *  /Users/TMWPmac/anaconda
PY27                     /Users/TMWPmac/anaconda/envs/PY27
PY36                     /Users/TMWPhmac/anaconda/envs/PY36
```

Change environments to PY36:

```
> source activate PY36
> conda env list
```

Output:

```
base                     /Users/TMWPmac/anaconda
PY27                     /Users/TMWPmac/anaconda/envs/PY27
PY36                  *  /Users/TMWPmac/anaconda/envs/PY36
```

Then I open a notebook and find that a library I only have installed on root still works and that a library I only have installed on `PY36` does not work (suggesting the change is not in effect on my active notebooks).

Even though I can work on my environments and use `conda install` in a separate terminal window from the terminal window that runs `jupyter notebook`, to be safe, I shut all down.  Then executed the commands to switch to `PY36` (and check the env list) first, executing `jupyter notebook` from the same terminal window. The problem persists across all notebooks after opening them in Jupyter.  The problem also persists if I open another terminal window and repeat the process to switch environments and then try to re-load the notebooks.

I can create environments and install libraries to them - but then I can't change to these to actually use what I have set up.  I am stuck in root always.

Anyone run into this and have a suggestion for how to fix it?

in case it helps - here is version info from my Jupyter notebook installation:

```
The version of the notebook server is 5.0.0 and is running on:
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:04:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)
```

This problem cropped up randomly after years of usage.  In the past, I am pretty sure that I would launch `jupyter notebook` in one terminal window, execute the `source activate` command in another and it would work on the active environment, but this does not now seem to be the case.